# How to disable button when one checkbox is not checked while other checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Hi I have a form with multiple checkboxes. It should be that when a master option is checked and a suboption is not, the user can not proceed to the next step.
I use the code below, but that ensures that when you enable and disable another suboption (of another main option) you can continue to the next step without checking a suboption of another main option.

The checkboxes:

```
<input name="input_1" type="checkbox" value="1" id="choice_1">
<input name="input_1.1" type="checkbox" value="1.1" id="choice_1_1">
<input name="input_1.2" type="checkbox" value="1.2" id="choice_1_2">
<input name="input_1.2" type="checkbox" value="1.3" id="choice_1_3">
<input name="input_1.3" type="checkbox" value="1.4" id="choice_1_4">

<input name="input_2" type="checkbox" value="2" id="choice_2">
<input name="input_2.1" type="checkbox" value="2.1" id="choice_2_1">
<input name="input_2.2" type="checkbox" value="2.2" id="choice_2_2">

<input name="input_3" type="checkbox" value="3" id="choice_3">
<input name="input_3.1" type="checkbox" value="3.1" id="choice_3_1">
<input name="input_3.2" type="checkbox" value="3.2" id="choice_3_2">
```

Jquery / Js

```
$('#choice_1').change(function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){

        if($("#choice_1:checked").length) {
            $("#field_18_104").hide(200);
        } 

          checked = $("#choice_1_1:checked").length || $("#choice_1_2:checked").length || $("#choice_1_3:checked").length || $("#choice_1_4:checked").length;

          if(!checked) {
            var $diverror = $( "<div id='error-form' class='error-form'><p>Error text</p></div>" );
            $("#input_18_26").append($diverror);
            $('#form_next_button').prop('disabled', true);
            return false;
          } else {
            $( "#error-form" ).remove();
            $('#form_next_button').prop('disabled', false);
          }

    } else {
        $( "#error-form" ).remove();
        $('#form_next_button').prop('disabled', false);

        // if($('#choice_18_26_3').prop('checked')){
        //  $('#choice_18_26_3').prop('checked', false).change();
        // } 
    }
});
```

I also use the js code for the main option and suboptions of options 2 and 3. This causes problems when for example main option 1 is checked without a suboption and main option 2 or 3 is checked with a suboption. Then the button is enabled again.

So there are actually 3 groups with suboptions, when group 1 the main option is checked and the suboptions are not and in group 2 a main option and suboption the user must not be able to continue.

The user should not be able to continue when a main option is checked without a sub-option.

Comment: You realise that your `<input>` elements aren't semantically/programatically grouped together since they *all* have different `name` attribute-values? If that's deliberate I don't understand, or *know*, your rationale, but if it's accidental then I'd suggest grouping them together `name="group1"`, `name="group2"` and so on.

Comment: @DavidThomas can't group them, is it not possible to do fix this with a function?

Answer (score 0):

try this:
 - be sure your checkbox are  inside a container, in my example gonna use  a div:

**#EDIT**

```
  <div id="checkContainer">
    <input name="input_1" type="checkbox" value="1" id="choice_1">
    <input name="input_1.1" type="checkbox" value="1.1" id="choice_1_1">
    <input name="input_1.2" type="checkbox" value="1.2" id="choice_1_2">
    <input name="input_1.2" type="checkbox" value="1.3" id="choice_1_3">
    <input name="input_1.3" type="checkbox" value="1.4" id="choice_1_4"> aaa
    <input name="input_2" type="checkbox" value="2" id="choice_2">
    <input name="input_2.1" type="checkbox" value="2.1" id="choice_2_1">
    <input name="input_2.2" type="checkbox" value="2.2" id="choice_2_2"> bbb
    <input name="input_3" type="checkbox" value="3" id="choice_3">
    <input name="input_3.1" type="checkbox" value="3.1" id="choice_3_1">
    <input name="input_3.2" type="checkbox" value="3.2" id="choice_3_2">
  </div>
  <button id="form_next_button" disabled>HI</button>
  <script>
    var MAIN_CHECBOX_SELECTOR = "input[type='checkbox']:not([value*='.'])";
//OR  var MAIN_CHECBOX_SELECTOR = "input[type='checkbox']:not([name*='.'])";
    var TOTAL_CHECKBOX = $(MAIN_CHECBOX_SELECTOR).length;
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#checkContainer").change(function () {
        var _checkedCheckboxes = $(MAIN_CHECBOX_SELECTOR + ":checked");
        //this might work as well:
        $('#form_next_button').prop('disabled', (_checkedCheckboxes.length !== TOTAL_CHECKBOX));
        // if (_checkedCheckboxes.length == TOTAL_CHECKBOX) {
        //   $('#form_next_button').prop('disabled', false);
        // } else {
        //   $('#form_next_button').prop('disabled', true);
        // }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: So there are actually 3 groups, when group 1 the main option is checked and the suboptions are not and in group 2 a main option and suboption the user must not be able to continue.

Comment: Not  really clear, 
do you mean that  the user can continue just  when the main options are checked? These 3 options?
 <input name="input_1" type="checkbox" value="1" id="choice_1">
<input name="input_2" type="checkbox" value="2" id="choice_2">
  <input name="input_3" type="checkbox" value="3" id="choice_3">

Comment: yes the users can now continue without checking a suboption when a main option is checked.

Comment: check my updated code, you should mark your main option with the data-attribute  data-main-option

Comment: @Michelle can't add data attribute to the options, is it not possible to do this with a function?

Comment: So we need something to mark the main options, if you are sure that the suboptions have always a dot "." in the name you can use my new script,
which relies in var MAIN_CHECBOX_SELECTOR = "input[type='checkbox']:not([value*='.'])";
OR  var MAIN_CHECBOX_SELECTOR = "input[type='checkbox']:not([name*='.'])";

Answer (score -1):

There were some small bits of ambiguity on your question but I believe you can work with this.

- This is very verbose but it should show what is happening.
- What it does:  disables subsequent checkbox groups if one does not have sub items.
- Does NOT un-check the sub groups if that occurs (was not specified but seems to make sense to do so - what if someone submits a form for example)
- IF you check a sub box, it auto checks the master for that group.
- You must un-check the master in a group manually if needed - might un-check if NO sub boxes are checked, but easy to refactor to do that.
- no fancy messaging or other fields not posted in your question manipulation, basic to address the check boxes only
- comments on JS should be removed prior to production publish perhaps.
- Note this "disables forward progress" by disabling subsequent groups, as long as you start with all unchecked that is fine, with initial unpredictable checked items it would be good to trigger this process on instantiation - probably on the first group such as: `$("input[name='input_1']").trigger('change');`

```js
$(function() {
  // change event for all named check boxes
  // note these are name prefix selectors
  $("input[name^='input_1']")
    .add("input[name^='input_2']")
    .add("input[name^='input_3']")
    .on('change', function() {
      console.log('change detected');
      // clear any prior message
      $('#showerrors').html("");
      // group 1 of checkboxes
      var choice1HasMaster = $("input[name='input_1']")[0].checked;
      // note that dot (.) on the prefix selector to get sub group: 
      var choice1HasSubcheck = !!$("input[name^='input_1.']")
        .filter(":checked").length;
      // check master if sub checked, update master bool
      choice1HasMaster = $("input[name='input_1']")[0].checked = choice1HasMaster || choice1HasSubcheck;
      var choice1OK = !choice1HasSubcheck || (choice1HasMaster && choice1HasSubcheck);
      // something in first group changed
      if ($(this).is("input[name^='input_1']")) {
        //  past here if needed disable
        if (choice1HasMaster && !choice1HasSubcheck) {
          $("input[name^='input_2']")
            .add("input[name^='input_3']")
            .each(function() {
              //uncheck sub group would trigger this function:
              //this.checked = false;
              $(this).prop('disabled', "disabled");
            });
          $('#showerrors').html("must check sub box group 1");
        } else {
          // enable next groups
          $("input[name^='input_2']")
            .add("input[name^='input_3']")
            .each(function() {
              $(this).prop('disabled', false);
            });
        }
      }
      var choice2HasMaster = $("input[name='input_2']")[0].checked;
      var choice2HasSubcheck = !!$("input[name^='input_2.']")
        .filter(":checked").length;
      // check master if sub checked, update master bool
      choice2HasMaster = $("input[name='input_2']")[0].checked = choice2HasMaster || choice2HasSubcheck;
      if ($(this).is("input[name^='input_2']")) {
        // past here if needed disable
        if (choice2HasMaster && !choice2HasSubcheck) {
          $("input[name^='input_3']")
            .each(function() {
              //uncheck sub group would trigger this function:
              // this.checked = false;
              $(this).prop('disabled', "disabled");
            });
          $('#showerrors').html($('#showerrors').text() + "must check sub box group 2");
        } else {
          $("input[name^='input_3']")
            .each(function() {
              $(this).prop('disabled', false);
            });
        }
      }
      var choice3HasMaster = $("input[name='input_3']")[0].checked;
      var choice3HasSubcheck = !!$("input[name^='input_3.']")
        .filter(":checked").length;
      // check master if sub checked, update master bool
      choice3HasMaster = $("input[name='input_3']")[0].checked = choice3HasMaster || choice3HasSubcheck;
      if (choice3HasMaster && !choice3HasSubcheck) {
        $('#showerrors').html($('#showerrors').text() + "must check sub box group 3");
      }
  
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="input_1" type="checkbox" value="1" id="choice_1">
<input name="input_1.1" type="checkbox" value="1.1" id="choice_1_1">
<input name="input_1.2" type="checkbox" value="1.2" id="choice_1_2">
<input name="input_1.2" type="checkbox" value="1.3" id="choice_1_3">
<input name="input_1.3" type="checkbox" value="1.4" id="choice_1_4"> group 2:
<input name="input_2" type="checkbox" value="2" id="choice_2">
<input name="input_2.1" type="checkbox" value="2.1" id="choice_2_1">
<input name="input_2.2" type="checkbox" value="2.2" id="choice_2_2"> group 3:
<input name="input_3" type="checkbox" value="3" id="choice_3">
<input name="input_3.1" type="checkbox" value="3.1" id="choice_3_1">
<input name="input_3.2" type="checkbox" value="3.2" id="choice_3_2">
<div id="showerrors"></div>
```